# In SSLCipherSuite, what is PROFILE=SYSTEM?

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl

As simple query: as per title header, what is "PROFILE=SYSTEM" for SSLCipherSuite referring to? What does it do?

I was previously reading through and trying to understand some inherited code, in particular with regards to static key ciphers, and I was wondering if this is the source of an issue.

I'm new to Apache, reading up and studying on various documentations with regards to it.

[One such document](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/linux-on-z?topic=cases-apache-http-server-usage-scenario#lxos_ibmca_p_configure__title__4) explains on how to configure the httpd, point #4 being the confusion in question.

Reading up on the [official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite)(at least, I think it is) didn't really explain much, or even alluded to the existence of this configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability to specify PROFILE=SYSTEM is a modification in Redhat/Fedora to allow for a single system wide cipher configuration for applications relying on OpenSSL. It cannot be found in official Apache or OpenSSL documentation since it is not part of their code but a vendor-specific modification.

See [0007-Add-support-for-PROFILE-SYSTEM-system-default-cipher.patch](https://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/fileinfo?rpmID=34642801&filename=0007-Add-support-for-PROFILE-SYSTEM-system-default-cipher.patch) and [Fedoraproject: Changes/CryptoPolicy](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/CryptoPolicy#Scope) and [Bug 1076390 - System-wide crypto policy](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1076390) and also the documentation on how to configure system wide crypto policies in RHEL8 [Chapter 4. Using system-wide cryptographic policies](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/using-the-system-wide-cryptographic-policies_security-hardening).

Comment: Tq for the links. Read the site, I dont get what do they mean by "system ciphers". Is it like a default; a built-in? Or does it refer to another file which list the ciphers used? Or something else?

Comment: @Erik: the idea is to have a single system wide configuration for all relevant TLS settings (protocol, ciphers) which includes all applications, libraries and programming languages and multiple TLS stacks (OpenSSL, GnuTLS, NSS, ...). So if a change is required for security reasons there is a single place to look it instead of the mess of finding out where are all the settings spread over the systems are.

Comment: Ulrich I think I get the general idea. But Im still a little confused. So, in the ```httpd.conf```, I set ```SSLCipherSuite PROFILE=SYSTEM```. This tells my code to refer to a system-wide configuration. So, say I need to change it due to trying to handle something called 'SSL Lucky13 Vulnerabilities'. Half the documentations Ive been reading says to change that very same ```SSLCipherSuite```; 'change' means remove the ```PROFILE-SYSTEM``` and replace it with something else? Or do I modify/append whatever configuration its referring to?

Comment: @Erik: With PROFILE=SYSTEM you don't make the change for each application but make it once system wide by using `update-crypto-policies`. See the extensive documentation from RHEL I've referenced for the details.

Comment: @Steffan Is it possible to change it on an application-basis? Say I want to add on a few on top of whatever is defined when PROFILE=SYSTEM is used? Or perhaps not use PROFILE=SYSTEM just for that one application but my own predefined list akin to ```SSLCipherSuite  PROFILE=SYSTEM ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:``` Your reference mentions creating a new file and link to it; as my server may be hosting multiple applications, I want to change just for the one and not affect the rest.

Comment: @Erik: Use of a system wide policy in your application is an explicit opt-in (using PROFILE=SYSTEM). If you want you can still use application specific policies as you did before.